# Mysql Insert, and insert in another if not exist

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO entity (name,surname,adr_id) values('test','test',< pseudocode see bellow >)
```

I want to check in table addresses by `street`,`town` and return that ID as `adr_id` or insert a new row in addresses.

So initially INSERT to have existing `adr_id` or a new, just created one.

**This is possible?**

Comment: Sorry, can you be more clear. The question is composed in the form of a riddle not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Insert ... On Duplicate... Update...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
Example :

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;
```